# how to remove inactive branches from github without a clone?

Tags: git, shell, github, devops

i wrote shell script for removing inactive branches from GitHub and it is cloning and deleting the inactive branches,but it will consume more memory and also we have more than thousand branches in every repo..

i am trying to remove unused/inactive branches without cloning repos/branches from Github.

```
!/usr/bin/bash
curl -i https://api.github.com/users/XXXX/repos -u XXXX:Token | sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g' | grep "name" | sed '/name/!d' | sed s/\"name\"://g | sed s/\"//g | sed s/\,//g | sed '/XXXX/d'| xargs -n1 &>> ./repolist.txt
filename=repolist.txt
while read -r line; do
    name="$line"
    echo "Name read from file - $name"
    git clone https://github.com/XXXX/$name.git
pwd
cd $name
git checkout master
#deleted merged branches on master branch
targetBranch=$(git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | sed 's/origin\///')
for branch in $targetBranch
do
 echo $branch
 lastDate=$(git show -s --format=%ci origin/$branch)
 convertDate=$(echo $lastDate | cut -d' ' -f 1)
 Todate=$(date -d "$convertDate" +'%s')
 current=$(date +'%s')
 day=$(( ( $current - $Todate )/60/60/24 ))
 echo "last commit on $branch branch was $day days ago" &>>./../last_commit_history_of_braches.txt
 if [ "$day" -gt 90 ]; then
    git push origin :$branch
    echo "delete the old branch $branch"
 fi
done
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: This doesn't look much like Node or Python, could you explain how those are relevant? I don't understand

Comment: may be we can able to use python or node.js for removing the branches from the github console.

Comment: Can’t you just `git push https://… :$foo`?

Comment: An abstract relation to a possible language for a solution is not enough to set a tag. Tags are important on SO to bring some structure into the huge number of questions. I took the freedom to remove both.

Comment: we can able to delete it from gitthub UI/console level using python and node.js scripts that is why i have tagged python and node.js.

Comment: shell script wont support for doing console level changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't clone the repository then.
Use the [GitHub Branch API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/), which can allow you to:

- [list branches](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#list-branches)
- for each branch, to [get the branch](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#get-branch), which includes the date of the latest commit.

And you can do so in a bash shell script, or a [python script with PyGitHub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub), or with javascript and [`octokit/rest.js`](https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/).

Comment: Thanks VonC finally i wrote and its working as expected.

Comment: @satishnakirikanti Well done! Do you have a gist on GitHub where you could publish that script?